# Inverse of 200000^x in R

Tags: r, math, scale, inverse

I wanted to graph a secondary axis using ggplot, I multiply my original data with 200000^[whole column], what's the inverse of this?

```
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.  ) )
```

Comment: If `y=a^x` then `x = log(y) / log(a)`.

Comment: *"multiply by"* or *"replace with"*? The former suggests `x * (200000^x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Nico's math, here's a working example using the inverse:

```r
set.seed(2)
z <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=200000^runif(100, 10, 11))

ggplot(z, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ log(.) / log(200000), breaks=c(10.1,10.9, 10.95)),
    expand = c(0,0)
  )
```

I had to use `expand=c(0,0)` because the expansion of the axis (common for context and clipping) resulted in negative values, even though there were no negative values in the data. These negatives resulted in warnings, so if you don't mind the warnings then you can exclude that. (There are likely other ways to deal with this phenomenon, perhaps they won't be necessary with *your* data.)

[image: sample ggplot graph with secondary axis]

**Edit**: I added `breaks=`. Note that `breaks=` and `labels=` can be overridden with numeric values or a function as input, so you don't need to hard-code the values as I have done here.

Comment: Is it possible to get the right Y axis to spread out the Y axis instead of cluster together  ? Thanks in advance .Let say,i want to convert the left side of Y axis in log base of 2  ?

Comment: Sure, if you read `?sec_axis`, it has both `breaks=` and `labels=` arguments (same functionality as the "normal" axis function arguments). (See my edit.)

Comment: Thanks! My data points is mostly in a base of log 2, when iam trying to use trans = log2_trans() on the left Y axis, I am getting an error "Error in if (max == min) return(base^min) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" , anything idea on how to avoid that?

Comment: That error is almost always because your condition (`(max==min)` here) is length 0. Check that it is always exactly length 1. I cannot find `log2_trans` anywhere.